# How do I prevent Bootstrap from collapsing into mobile view when width is below 768px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3. I wish to prevent Bootstrap from changing the styling of the page when the width goes below 768px. The reason is that Bootstrap will stack div rows on top of each other and I don't want that.

Here's what I did:

```
@media (max-width : 768px)  {
  .container {
    width: 800px;
  }
}
```

It successfully set the container width to 800px but it didn't prevent the styling of the container from being changed (i.e. the elements are still being stacked).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="clearfix inbox-panel row">
    <div class="convo-panel col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">

      <div class="clearfix panel panel-default">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Sent</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- List group -->
        <ul class="convo-list list-group">
          <div class="push"></div>  
        </ul>
        <div class="convo-footer">
          <div class="convo-features">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="edit-convo-button btn btn-default">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="mark-all-read-button btn btn-default">Mark all as read</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="convo-options">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">

                <button type="button" class="mark-read-button btn btn-default">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                  Mark as read
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="delete-convo-button btn btn-default">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                  Delete
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="cancel-button btn btn-default">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  Cancel
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix chat-panel col-md-7 col-sm-7">
      <div class="clearfix chat-header row">
        <div class="sender-chat-photo col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-2">
          <img class="img-circle" src="/images/no_photo_thumb.png">
          <div class="online-indicator"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sender-chat-info col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-5">
          <p class="truncate list-group-item-heading sender-name">
            <span class="vip-label label label-default"></span>
          </p>
          <p class="truncate small list-group-item-text sender-location"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-5">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Options </span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Block user</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Report user</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Delete conversation</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix chat-box">
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix chat-input-panel">
        <div class="clearfix row">
          <div class="chat-input-form col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="chat-input" placeholder="Type your message here..."><%= current_user.token %></textarea>
            <button type="button" class="chat-input-button btn btn-default">Send</button>
            <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
          </div>
        </div> 

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/chat.js"></script> 
<script>
  startChat('<%= current_user.token %>');
</script>
```

Comment: please post the html

Answer (score 1):

You will chase your tail *forever* with the method you've tried. Presuming you're not using SASS or LESS where you can set variables before the Bootstrap CSS is generated, try using the [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/). Go to [customizer's breakpoints section](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) and set the `@screen-sm` variable to a lower value like `650px`.

Comment: Yes I'm not using SASS but I think it's better to use it. What is the way to do set breakpoints if you use SASS?

Comment: You can add a variable to your own SASS style sheet named `$screen-sm`. See the syntax here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L300

Comment: Can it override Bootstrap CSS files loaded from CDN?

Comment: You _can_ but you will almost certainly hate your life with all of the tail chasing. Bootstrap CDN is very much for those who are ok with the defaults, particularly the breakpoints.